# PHP : traversing multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I've an array in library management system that has a user on first index,books assigned to that user on next index and then details about books assigned  like this.

this is what i need to show in table form

[image]

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => 
                    [email] => test@test.com
                    [password] => test
                    [role] => 
                    [status] => 1
                )

        )

    [books] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 1
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-24 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 2
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-24 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [user_id] => 5
                    [book_id] => 1
                    [date_issue] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                    [date_return] => 2016-07-25 00:00:00
                )

        )

    [bookdata] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [title] => PHP Made Easy 
                            [author] => Dietel & Dietel 
                            [serial_no] => 232323
                            [qty] => 9
                            [row_no] => 1
                            [col_no] => 2
                            [status] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [description] => This is a book about php 
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [title] => C++
                            [author] => Dietel & Dietel 
                            [serial_no] => 232323
                            [qty] => 9
                            [row_no] => 1
                            [col_no] => 2
                            [status] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [description] => This is a book about c++
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [title] => PHP Made Easy 
                            [author] => Dietel & Dietel 
                            [serial_no] => 232323
                            [qty] => 9
                            [row_no] => 1
                            [col_no] => 2
                            [status] => 1
                            [category_id] => 1
                            [description] => This is a book about php 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

this is how i try to parse like this

```
 foreach ($data  as  $key=> $value) {
        echo $key[$value]->id;
    }
```

the error i get

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal offset type
>
> Filename: views/history.php
>
> Line Number: 4

Please help me to parse this array

Comment: what do you mean by "parsing"? what's the expected result? do you mean "traversing" instead?

Comment: please post final output you want

Comment: i mean i need to print these results in html table

Comment: i want it to be printed it in a table where it shows username , books assigned , date issued , date return etc

Comment: `echo $key[0]->id;`

Comment: show your expected outcome that you want?

Comment: Where originally does the data come from?

Comment: i am doing it in codeigniter and  i pasted what i got from my controller. print_r give me above output and i need to show in as aove attached datble

Answer (score 0):

this array object, try to get object as array by using like this.

```
$data_new = (array) $data;
```

This will convert your array object to array format.after that you can pass this to foreach.
or else you can use below function

```
function object_to_array($obj) {
    $arr = is_object($obj) ? get_object_vars($obj) : $obj;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
            $val = (is_array($val) || is_object($val)) ? object_to_array($val) : $val;
            $arr[$key] = $val;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

This is not an actual direct answer for your question,But i am suggesting you that you can try in this way too,If answer is helped mark as answer :).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this,

1. Stop looping this type of multidimensional array. This array formation is wrong if you are expecting output shown in post.
2. Try to remove extra unnecessary nesting

   ```
           [0] => Array (
               [0] => stdClass Object
                   (
                       [id] => 1
                       [title] => PHP Made Easy
   ```
3. Divide you array and save it in different variable for e.g.

   $userInfo = $array[user][0];

   $books = $array[books];

   $bookdata = $array[bookdata];
4. Here onwards you can loop and start adding data to your empty array maintaining key/per record. This key will help you to loop it in a table...

Answer (score 0):

According to your array structure, it's a an array object.

You have to use call array key name to traverse array objects within your main loop. So you can do it as below mention.

```
//main loop
foreach ($data  as  $key=> $value) {

    //get user info
    echo $value['user'][0]->id;

    //get books info
    for($i=0; $i < count($value['books']); $i++) {
        echo $value['books'][$i]->id;
    }

    //get further books info
    foreach($value['bookdata'] as $books) {
        echo $books->author;
    }

}
```

Now you can use this to populate HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only a single user per array, you could just loop through the array; using `conditional Logic` to decide the Current Key (like books, user)... and from there, you can just build a HTML Table containing your required Output. A test might be in Order and [you can find the test here](https://eval.in/611359).

```
<?php

    $tblOutput  = "<div class='books-wrapper col-md-12'>"                               . PHP_EOL;
    if(!empty($arrBkLib)){

        foreach($arrBkLib as $key=>$data){
            if($key == 'user' && !empty($data[0])){
                $userName   = isset($data[0]->name) ? $data[0]->name : "N/A";

                $tblOutput .= "<div class='user-data-pane col-md-6  pull-left'>"        . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<span class='btn btn-custom'>{$userName}</span>"         . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "</div>"                                                  . PHP_EOL;

                $tblOutput .= "<div class='action-pane  col-md-6  pull-right'>"         . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<a class='btn btn-custom'>Ban User</a>"                  . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "</div>"                                                  . PHP_EOL;


                $tblOutput .= "<table class='tbl-books-data'>"                          . PHP_EOL;

                $tblOutput .= "<tr class='tbl-books-data-head-row'>"                    . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-head-cell'>Book</th>"          . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-head-cell'>Issue Date</th>"    . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-head-cell'>Return Date</th>"   . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-head-cell'>Fine</th>"          . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-head-cell'>Status</th>"        . PHP_EOL;
                $tblOutput .= "</tr>"                                                   . PHP_EOL;

            }else if($key == 'books' && !empty($data)){
                foreach($data as $iKey=>$books) {
                    $issueDate  = isset($books->date_issue)    ? date("d/m/Y", strtotime($books->date_issue))   : "N/A";
                    $returnDate = isset($books->date_return)   ? date("d/m/Y", strtotime($books->date_return))  : "N/A";
                    $bookName   = isset($arrBkLib['bookdata'][$iKey]->title)    ? $arrBkLib['bookdata'][$iKey]->title   : "N/A";
                    $status     = isset($arrBkLib['bookdata'][$iKey]->status)   ? $arrBkLib['bookdata'][$iKey]->status  : "N/A";
                    $fine       = "N/A";    // USE YOUR LOGIC HERE TO DETERMINE THIS VALUE...

                    $tblOutput .= "<tr class='tbl-books-data-row'>"                     . PHP_EOL;
                    $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-cell'>{$bookName}</th>"    . PHP_EOL;
                    $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-cell'>{$issueDate}</th>"   . PHP_EOL;
                    $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-cell'>{$returnDate}</th>"  . PHP_EOL;
                    $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-cell'>{$fine}</th>"        . PHP_EOL;
                    $tblOutput .= "<th class='tbl-books-data-cell'>{$status}</th>"      . PHP_EOL;
                    $tblOutput .= "</tr>"                                               . PHP_EOL;
                }
            }
        }
        $tblOutput .= "</table>" . PHP_EOL;
        $tblOutput .= "</div>"   . PHP_EOL;
    }

echo $tblOutput;
```